# Conflict between with a function in two different modules

Tags: 7, theming

I have the same function in two different modules to change the page: **node/add**.

I need the second one(see below) to override the first one. I implemented hook_install to change their weight but is not working. My guess is that the hook_install function is executed after those modules.

How can get this done?

Codes below:

My hook_install function

```
/**
* Implements hook_install().
*/
function utilities_install(){

db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('weight' => 10000))
    ->condition('name', '[content_type_thumbnail]', '=')
    ->execute();

}
```

Function in **commerce_backoffice_product** module:

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function commerce_backoffice_product_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['node_add_list']['function'] = 'theme_commerce_backoffice_product_node_add_list';
}

/**
 * Override node_add_list theme.
 */
function theme_commerce_backoffice_product_node_add_list($variables) {
  $item = menu_get_item();

   .... code ....

  return theme_node_add_list($variables);
}
```

Function in **content_type_thumbnail** module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function content_type_thumbnail_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['node_add_list']['function'] = 'content_type_thumbnail_node_add_list';
}

/**
 * Override of theme_node_add_list().
 */
function content_type_thumbnail_node_add_list($variables) {

  .... code ....

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: I´d like to know the reason of the down vote. This question is about function overlapping. It could be useful in other situations for other people.

Comment: Err did you un install and re install your module(s) after you changed the weight ? .install files will only be used while installing or updating. So if you had already installed it, weights will not change unless you re installed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than module weighting, I would suggest using [hook_module_implements_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to ensure your hook gets run last. So, something like this:

```
function hook_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'theme_registry_alter') {
    $group = $implementations['my_module'];
    unset($implementations['my_module']);
    $implementations['my_module'] = $group;
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't know that you can order the hooks executions. Thanks Alfred.

Comment: Yes, that piece of knowledge is something that needs to be spread more widely.